# Relax the requirements for "crazy formatting" on the /tour example question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

On Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, the answers to most of our questions look like this:

> ### Some language, 1234 characters
>
> ```
> asdfunicorn+1(&&%^#$)/-9x9[{}]
> ```
>
> {explanation text goes here)

That's a pretty big problem for the [/tour](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) page, since apparently the requirement of ["no crazy formatting"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/180276) means "no lists, quotes, code, images, or headers." For that reason, we have exactly zero choices (out of 1993 questions) for our /tour page's example question on PPCG.

Could these very tight requirements be loosened a little? I can understand the < 400 character and no image requirements, but can at least a single line of code and a single header be allowed? If not, I fear that PPCG will never be able to get rid of the "unicorns eating daisies" example question (not saying unicorns are any less majestic; they're just not good at code golf).

Comment: There is a per-site setting for this, we have a relaxed one on Skeptics as we otherwise have no useful choice for the about page.

Comment: @MadScientist Wait, there is? I wouldn't have had to post this if I knew that. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: There is a bit about this in the comments on [this post here on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192092/what-are-the-exact-criteria-for-the-example-question-on-about), but there is no real documentation as far as I know. The setting can only be changed by SE employees anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've lifted the prohibition on block elements for this site, so moderators can now choose from a fairly diverse list of questions.

The length limit still applies, and if block elements make the posts too big for the available space they'll just be truncated. As such, you'll want to be a bit careful when choosing a question to avoid those that look really bad - or only have poor answers that fit within the length criteria.

Comment: Thanks, our /tour page is now decidedly less unicorny!